# Calling Normal Module Sub in Class module in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined a public sub in a common module (normal module). I am trying to access this in class module.
Below is both the code -

```
Public loadGroupIndicator As Boolean

Public Sub stopLoadGroupIndicator()
    loadGroupIndicator = False
End Sub

Public Sub startLoadGroupIndicator()
    loadGroupIndicator = True
End Sub

Public Sub getLoadGroupIndicator()
    getLoadGroupIndicator = loadGroupIndicator
End Sub
```

I am trying to use "getLoadGroupIndicator" function in below function of a class module (testClass)

```
' This is in testClass
' Private sub to execute something on the event
Private Sub m_chckBox_Click()
    If getLoadGroupIndicator Then
        MsgBox "loadGroupIndicatorLocal is true"
    Else
        MsgBox "some other msg based on the object property"
    End If
End Sub
```

I am getting the below error msg

[image]

Please help me fix this. I am new to VBA and struggling on this since yesterday.
Thanks in advance for any help or relevant pointers.

Comment: A sub doesn't return anything, but as the error says, it would likely work with a function. Change `Public Sub getLoadGroupIndicator()` to `Public Function getLoadGroupIndicator() as Boolean` maybe? I've never worked with classes, so not sure how this is accessed.

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristoferWeber! changing "sub" to "Function" worked

Comment: Seems strange to me not to access the loadGroupIndicator boolean directly though.

Comment: Actually I started with that only but I was not able to make it work